# How to get HttpSamplerProxy elements like HeaderManager and its added Header programmatically

Tags: java, spring, jmeter, jira-rest-api

I have a requirement where I'm adding headers programmatically and creating my jmxscript, but know I want to retrieve HeaderManager with its added headers.

this is the code to add header programmatically

```
    HeaderManager headerManager = new HeaderManager();
    headerManager.add(new Header("Content-Type", "application/json"));
```

I'm getting this data provided into JMX script like this.

```
<org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree>
          <HeaderManager guiclass="HeaderPanel" testclass="HeaderManager" testname="HTTP Header Manager">
            <collectionProp name="HeaderManager.headers">
              <elementProp name="Content-Type" elementType="Header">
                <stringProp name="Header.name">Content-Type</stringProp>
                <stringProp name="Header.value">application/json</stringProp>
              </elementProp>
            </collectionProp>
          </HeaderManager>
          <org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree/>
        </org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree>
```

I tried  like this but not working getting null.

```
        headerManager=httpSampler.getHeaderManager();
        PropertyIterator  iter= headerManager.getHeaders().iterator();
        while(iter.hasNext()) {
        String name=iter.next().getName();
        String value=iter.next().getStringValue();
        addParameters.put(name, value);
```

How do I get out of this?

Answer (score 1):

The correct code for [HeaderManager](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/control/HeaderManager.html) initialization and adding the relevant [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) header would be something like:

```
HeaderManager headerManager = new HeaderManager();
headerManager.setName("HTTP Header Manager");
headerManager.add(new Header("Content-Type", "application/json"));
headerManager.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, HeaderManager.class.getName());
headerManager.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, HeaderPanel.class.getName());
```

Just in case full code to create a JMeter test plan with a single HTTP Request sampler and a HTTP Header Manager added as a child of this sampler:

```
package com.example;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.jmeter.config.Arguments;
import org.apache.jmeter.config.gui.ArgumentsPanel;
import org.apache.jmeter.control.LoopController;
import org.apache.jmeter.control.gui.LoopControlPanel;
import org.apache.jmeter.control.gui.TestPlanGui;
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.Header;
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.HeaderManager;
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.gui.HttpTestSampleGui;
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.gui.HeaderPanel;
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy;
import org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService;
import org.apache.jmeter.testelement.TestElement;
import org.apache.jmeter.testelement.TestPlan;
import org.apache.jmeter.threads.ThreadGroup;
import org.apache.jmeter.threads.gui.ThreadGroupGui;
import org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterUtils;
import org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree;

public class JMeterFromCode {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String slash = System.getProperty("file.separator");
        File jmeterHome = new File("c:/apps/jmeter");
        File jmeterProperties = new File(jmeterHome.getPath() + slash + "bin" + slash + "jmeter.properties");


        //JMeter initialization (properties, log levels, locale, etc)
        JMeterUtils.setJMeterHome(jmeterHome.getPath());
        JMeterUtils.loadJMeterProperties(jmeterProperties.getPath());


        // JMeter Test Plan, basically JOrphan HashTree
        HashTree testPlanTree = new HashTree();

        // HTTP Request Sampler
        HTTPSamplerProxy httpRequest = new HTTPSamplerProxy();
        httpRequest.setDomain("example.com");
        httpRequest.setPort(80);
        httpRequest.setPath("/");
        httpRequest.setMethod("GET");
        httpRequest.setName("HTTP Request");
        httpRequest.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, HTTPSamplerProxy.class.getName());
        httpRequest.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, HttpTestSampleGui.class.getName());

        // HTTP Header Manager
        HeaderManager headerManager = new HeaderManager();
        headerManager.setName("HTTP Header Manager");
        headerManager.add(new Header("Content-Type", "application/json"));
        headerManager.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, HeaderManager.class.getName());
        headerManager.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, HeaderPanel.class.getName());


        // Loop Controller
        LoopController loopController = new LoopController();
        loopController.setLoops(1);
        loopController.setFirst(true);
        loopController.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, LoopController.class.getName());
        loopController.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, LoopControlPanel.class.getName());
        loopController.initialize();

        // Thread Group
        ThreadGroup threadGroup = new ThreadGroup();
        threadGroup.setName("Example Thread Group");
        threadGroup.setNumThreads(1);
        threadGroup.setRampUp(1);
        threadGroup.setSamplerController(loopController);
        threadGroup.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, ThreadGroup.class.getName());
        threadGroup.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, ThreadGroupGui.class.getName());

        // Test Plan
        TestPlan testPlan = new TestPlan("Create JMeter Script From Java Code");
        testPlan.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, TestPlan.class.getName());
        testPlan.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, TestPlanGui.class.getName());
        testPlan.setUserDefinedVariables((Arguments) new ArgumentsPanel().createTestElement());

        // Construct Test Plan from previously initialized elements
        testPlanTree.add(testPlan);
        HashTree threadGroupHashTree = testPlanTree.add(testPlan, threadGroup);
        HashTree httpSamplerHashTree = new HashTree();
        httpSamplerHashTree.add(httpRequest, headerManager);
        threadGroupHashTree.add(httpSamplerHashTree);

        // save generated test plan to JMeter's .jmx file format
        SaveService.saveTree(testPlanTree, new FileOutputStream(jmeterHome + slash + "example.jmx"));

    }
}
```

More information: [Five Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui/)

Comment: Hi, Dmitri I saw your code earlier I added HeaderManager like your only, but now I'm traversing JMX script and getting sampler hash tree but don't know how to retrieve HeaderManager from samplers.thanks.

Comment: I want Content-type and application/json  to add in Map.

Comment: You will be able to use [httpSampler.getHeaderManager()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPSamplerBase.html#getHeaderManager--) function **only in JMeter runtime** from, i.e. [JSR223 Test Elements using Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/), if you call this function in the Java class which creates the .jmx script you will get `null`. If you want to do something in the class which generates the .jmx - just use `headerManager ` object.

Comment: whenever I use httpSamplerProxyTree.getHeaderManager i get null value .why so?

Comment: You need to call [HTTPSamplerBase.setHeaderManager() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPSamplerBase.html#setHeaderManager-org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.HeaderManager-) first or just run JMeter test, in the runtime it will not be null. If you're not too comfortable with JMeter API you could consider [Taurus tool](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/navigating-your-first-steps-using-taurus/) as an alternative way to create a JMeter test, see [Building Test Plan from Config](https://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/#Building-Test-Plan-from-Config)